# Wordpress wp editor

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to integrate wp_editor in a popup. I used this function

```
$content = '';
$editor_id ='content';
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id);
```

but on submit, I didn't get any data.
I also tried to integrate featured image meta box in that pop up. I'm using this

```
add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Featured Image'),'post_thumbnail_meta_box', $post_type, 'side', 'low');
```

but i didn't get any meta box.

Comment: First of all, do not directly call add_meta_box(). your add_meta_box method needs to be inside a function just like that: add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );   function myplugin_add_meta_box() {
  add_meta_box(
   'postimagediv',
   __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
   'post_thumbnail_meta_box',
   $your_post_type, 'side', 'low');
 }
}
You are also missing your theme's text domain. so check that also.

Comment: You can then call wp_editor( $content, $editor_id); inside your render function `post_thumbnail_meta_box()`